# Eloquent 2 left join query

Tags: sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I would like to execute the following query using Laravel's eloquent query builder:

```
SELECT a.*, b.day, c.sex FROM hours as a
left join reserves as b
on a.id = b.hour_id and b.day = '2015-12-12'
left join doctors as c
on a.doctor_id = c.id
where a.doctor_id = 1;
```

I have tried the following:

```
Hour::leftJoin('reserves', function($join) {
    $join->on('hours.id' , '=' , 'reserves.hour_id')
        ->where('reserves.day' , '=' , '2015-12-12');
})
->leftJoin('doctors', function($join) {
    $join->on('hours.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id'); 
})
->where('hours.doctor_id', '=', $doctorId)
->get();
```

Unfortunately, I am not getting the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine, however you miss selecting columns, after `Hour::` you should add:

```
select('hours.*'.'reserves.day','doctors.sex')->
```

You could also make second join simpler and use aliases, so the final code could look like this:

```
Hour::select('hours.*'.'reserves.day','doctors.sex')
     ->from('hours AS a')
     ->leftJoin('reserves AS b', function($join) {
         $join->on('a.id' , '=' , 'b.hour_id')
        ->where('b.day' , '2015-12-12');
     })
    ->leftJoin('doctors AS c', 'a.doctor_id', '=', 'c.id')
    ->where('a.doctor_id', $doctorId)
    ->get();
```

Of course as `$doctorId` you should set `1` to get exact same result

Answer (score 0):

you can use DB::raw :

```
Hour::select(DB::raw('hours.*'),reserves.day, c.doctors)
->leftJoin('reserves',DB::raw("hours.id = reserves.hour_id AND reserves.day='2015-12-12'")  ,DB::raw(''), DB::raw(''))
->leftJoin('doctors','hours.doctor_id', '=', 'doctors.id')
->where('hours.doctor_id', '=', $doctorId)
->get()
```

the 2 empty DB::raw is because leftJoin expect 4 arguments`(table,columnA,operator,columnB)`